# Read Commited Isolation level not working

Tags: java, multithreading, postgresql, jdbc, isolation-level

I'm trying to understand the ACID isolation principal. I have coded this portion of code:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        Runnable t2 = () -> {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Connection connection;

            try {
                connection = this.iDatabaseConnector.getConnection();

                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM mssmbank.mssmbank.bankaccounts WHERE id = ?");
                preparedStatement.setInt(1, 490);

                ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                resultSet.next();

                System.out.println("Result: " + resultSet.getDouble("BALANCE"));

                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        Runnable t1 = () -> {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Connection connection;

            try {
                connection = this.iDatabaseConnector.getConnection();
                connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);

                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE mssmbank.mssmbank.bankaccounts " + "SET balance = ? WHERE id = ?");
                preparedStatement.setDouble(1, (new Random()).nextInt(1000));
                preparedStatement.setInt(2, 490);
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                ExecutorService executorService1 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                executorService1.execute(t2);

                Thread.sleep(3_000);

                connection.commit();
                connection.close();

                executorService1.shutdown();
                executorService1.awaitTermination(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (SQLException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        executorService.execute(t1);
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

There are 2 threads, *t1* and *t2*. *t1* is supposed to **update** a bank account row in the database, and *t2* is supposed to **read** its balance.

Here's the scenario: *t1* start, open a connection, makes an update and **doesn't commit**. It triggers *t2* and **sleeps** for 3 seconds.

*t2* starts, opens a connection, reads the balance and prints it (basically the old one because *t1* hasn't committed yet) then close the connection.

Then *t1* finishes by **committing** the update and the program ends.

What I'm expecting to happen, is that *t2* gets blocked until *t1* has finished committing because *t2* is accessing the same bank account row (*t1* should have locked the row for update). Therefore, *t2* should have printed the updated balance of the bank account #490, not the previous one.

Why doesn't *t1* lock the row? why isn't *t2* getting blocked? 
Note that the *isolation Level* is set to `TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED`.

Comment: That's not how transaction read committed works.  t2 gets the prior committed value, the previous value.  That's why you generally update and commit quickly, to minimize the window where another transaction can read ab old, previously committed value.

Comment: Thank you, this is clear. so this is not a scenario about dirty read right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select statement in t2 is not getting blocked because it is only attempting to read not write. If you were to attempt to perform an update (or select...for update), then it could block if your timeout is set to wait for some length of time before giving up. You don't mention which database you're using, but here's some nice docs on how Postgres handles locking: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html

Comment: Thank you clear answer. Yes i'm using PostgreSQL. But tell me, isn't this scenario an example of dirty read ? or is the dirty read only related to when a rollback happens ?

Comment: My pleasure. Regarding dirty reads, this is not possible in PostgreSQL. For details see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html.

Comment: Oh rights, i can see from the table there that Dirty Read never happens in PostgreSQL. Thank you so much !

Comment: I changed the DatabaseConnector to a MySQL Connector, and tried the same process (same code) and it performs as well a dirty read right. so either UNCOMMITED or COMMITED Isolation level has been set for PostgreSQL it will always disallow dirty reads. Sounds more secure than MySQL !